# Cannot create Entity Subscription with Network Id

Tags: apex, community, customer-community

Hello I have to create an entity subscriptions for portal enabled users through my apex

```
Community community = [ SELECT Id FROM Community WHERE Name = 'Internal Ideas'];
EntitySubscription es = new EntitySubscription();
                        es.NetworkId = community.Id;
                        es.SubscriberId = usr.Id;
                        es.ParentId = oppId;
                        esList.add(es);
```

but I m ending up with following error

11:41:47:848 USER_DEBUG [97]|DEBUG|Exception***System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Network ID: id value of incorrect type: 09a30000000096rAAA: [NetworkId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommunityID is different from NetworkID .

You will need to query the Salesforce Network table .

```
Network networkRec = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'xyz' limit 1];
```